# Visual Studio BFS Code working on in debugging mode but normal run mode?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, breadth-first-search

When running my code below, which searches through a maze using a queue, it runs properly on the debug mode of Visual Studio but not when I run it without debugging. It doesn't return properly and sometimes prints the wrong values (such as duplicate values when they shouldn't occur). When I run the program multiple times without changing anything, it produces a different output.

I have tested the code on online compilers and on someone else's Visual Studio which seem to all generate the correct response. I have traced through the code manually and it seems to be working fine as well. I've also tried deleting and reinstalling Visual Studio 2022. I've looked for uninitialized memory but it doesn't seem to be the issue. Is there a reason for this?

```
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool pathExists(string maze[], int nRows, int nCols, int sr, int sc, int er, int ec);
// Return true if there is a path from (sr,sc) to (er,ec)
// through the maze; return false otherwise

class Coord
{
public:
    Coord(int r, int c) : m_row(r), m_col(c) {}
    int r() const { return m_row; }
    int c() const { return m_col; }
private:
    int m_row;
    int m_col;
};

bool pathExists(string maze[], int nRows, int nCols, int sr, int sc, int er, int ec)
{
    stack<Coord> coordStack;
    coordStack.push(Coord(sr, sc));
    maze[sr][sc] = 'v';

    while (!coordStack.empty())
    {
        Coord pos = coordStack.top();
        cerr << pos.r() << ' ' << pos.c() << endl;
        coordStack.pop();
        if (pos.r() == er && pos.c() == ec)
            return true;
        if (pos.c() + 1 >= 0 && pos.c() + 1 < nCols)
        {
            if (maze[pos.r()][pos.c() + 1] == '.')
            {
                coordStack.push(Coord(pos.r(), pos.c() + 1));
                maze[pos.r()][pos.c() + 1] = 'v';
            }
        }
        if (pos.r() - 1 >= 0 && pos.r() - 1 < nRows)
        {
            if (maze[pos.r() - 1][pos.c()] == '.')
            {
                coordStack.push(Coord(pos.r() - 1, pos.c()));
                maze[pos.r() - 1][pos.c()] = 'v';
            }
        }
        if (pos.c() - 1 >= 0 && pos.c() - 1 < nCols)
        {
            if (maze[pos.r()][pos.c() - 1] == '.')
            {
                coordStack.push(Coord(pos.r(), pos.c() - 1));
                maze[pos.r()][pos.c() - 1] = 'v';
            }
        }
        if (pos.r() + 1 >= 0 && pos.r() + 1 < nRows)
        {
            if (maze[pos.r() + 1][pos.c()] == '.')
            {
                coordStack.push(Coord(pos.r() + 1, pos.c()));
                maze[pos.r() + 1][pos.c()] = 'v';
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    string maze[10] = {
        "XXXXXXXXXX",
        "X..X...X.X",
        "X.XXXX.X.X",
        "X.X.X..X.X",
        "X...X.XX.X",
        "XXX......X",
        "X.X.XXXX.X",
        "X.XXX....X",
        "X...X..X.X",
        "XXXXXXXXXX"
    };

    if (pathExists(maze, 10, 10, 5, 3, 8, 8))
        cerr << "Solvable!" << endl;
    else
        cerr << "Out of luck!" << endl;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: *I've also tried deleting and reinstalling Visual Studio 2022* -- I'll be honest -- that's a waste of time.  The issue is with your code, not the compiler.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think the code works since I've tested on another person's Visual Studio, on XCode, and on online compilers.

Comment: *it runs properly on the debug mode of Visual Studio but not when I run it without debugging* -- Does this mean that you are running a debug version, but without debugging it?  Or did you build a release version and running the release version?

Comment: I built a release version and I'm running the release version.

Comment: You can still debug the release version.  What happens if you did that?

Comment: I think the release version works if you debug it.

Comment: I tried debugging the release version and it worked as intended.